# How do I change the web site summary in search results?

Tags: search-engines

I have a web site that I am working on, hendersonvillecameraclub.org.  When I use Google to search for the site using 'hendersonville camera club' as the search terms my site is the 6th result.  Below the page title, it gives a snippet of the most recent post on the site.  My question is, how do I change what information is displayed in the summary?  I would prefer to put some static text there that provides a better description of the site.

This site is hosted by GoDaddy, not sure if that's relevant information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an SEO or meta tag plugin that will give you the most options to work with meta for the home page, for post pages, static pages, etc. It's not enough to simply add one metatag to the header template.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=SEO&sort=

Comment: I strongly recommend Yoast SEO Plugin http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/. It takes care of that very well, and does many other things you won't regret :)

Comment: @pixeline, You're better off adding your comment to Tim's question above; he's looking for the plugin, not me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions, just what I was looking for.  I'm going to give Yoast a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your meta description:

> "a default installation of WordPress does not contain the description
>   and keywords meta tag data"

To add meta tags to your site, simply add them to the header.php template file in your WordPress Theme, specifically in the head section near the link for the style sheet. See the following link for full instructions:

[Meta Tags in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress)

Also, see [the Google commentary on meta descriptions](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35624#1).